# How to handle a large no. of observers to be updated efficiently w.r.t. time in the Observer Patterns

Tags: java

If i have a large no. of observers(50 +) then how should i call update() on observers .I do not want to process the update one by one .Is there any other efficient way to organize observers for update

Comment: I would be careful about premature optimization. Have you *measured* and verified that you really have a problem here? It would not surprise me if your problem is not the high number of observers - but for example that the observers are doing all work on the event dispatcher thread - instead of using a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities:

1. There are several very optimized EventBus implementations available for Java, for example in Guava. You can configure them to use multiple threads to update all observers.
2. Alternatively, you can use a ThreadPool and make a new thread to update, say, 20 observers. You'll want to use a ThreadPool so that you don't create a new thread each time but reuse an older one.
3. If many observers execute the same code, you can let a helper object execute that code and let the other observers observe that helper object instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the update method all observer method in the same thread ,you can create a thread pool and create separate worker thread to perform update operation.

Example code:

```
 for (int i = arrLocal.length-1; i>=0; i--){
executor.execute(new Runnable() {
          @Override

          public void run() {
            ((Observer)arrLocal[i]).update(this, arg);
          }
        });
}
```